How do I set boundary while learning something and verify if I learnt that thing in a non-academic setting?
I was reviewing my learning progress so far this month and I found an important factor that's hindering my progress.
I really get stuck while studying a lot. And I think it's a good thing as it means I encountered something new.
For example:
I am learning about DNS and getting stuck on implementing the various types of name servers. I've read most of the things about DNS found in textbooks. I think my concept is clear about DNS, but I am unable to implement them in Linux server(not code them, just setup them).
I've completed the setup via https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-with-bind/
tutorials like this which tells me how to do it. Also read parts of books like Evi Nemeth's unix and linux sysadmin handbook, TCPIP network administrators guide, Pro DNS and BIND 10. But I still feel I don't really "made it to stick".

How do I test/verify if I learnt something when I am learning something in a non-academic scenario, and not doing it for my current job? (Example: I learnt by exercises on textbooks while learning for university exams)

How do I define to which "depth" to learn a topic? Or how do I set a boundary while learning?

How to determine the optimum interleaving of subjects? I am a kind of a person who learns better by switching between different subjects(say computer networks, algorithms and database). But how many subjects switching is optimum? Has there been any research about it?



By far the most common way would be to enroll in a class; though we can debate about the costs of education and who should pay them, the reason it exists at all is to have professionals guide students in exactly these things. If it were something you could do yourself after reading a SE Q&A I guess we wouldn't really need universities.

I worry this question may not be a good fit for Academia SE, as it seems to focus on self-study and not learning in the context of an academic institution.

@BryanKrause university is not an option. I've enrolled in some online GATE computer science classes. Likewise, for some stuffs, they have certification exams which I study for or enroll in an udemy course to learn.
